# Interface builder label not the right position

Tags: objective-c

i'm working in Interface Builder right now but my UIlabel not stand on the right position.
The label is moving.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Interface :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it getting moved because the view is getting resized. In IB, you're designing it with a bottom bar, but there is no bottom bar in your app. This causes the view to be resized to fit, potentially moving around your other UI elements.